# Set result of MySQL query into a JComboBox

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, swing

I'm designing an application in Eclipse using Window Builder (Swing).
I have a mysql query that select a code and I need to put the result of the query in a combobox and I don't know how to make that.
Sorry if I'm not explaning well, my English isn't flow.

```
comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            Connection conexion=null;
            try{
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                conexion=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/gestion_alumnos","root","");
                Statement selcod=conexion.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs=selcod.executeQuery("select clave from alumnos");
                while(rs.next()){
                    comboBox.addItem(rs.getString(1));
                }
                ResultSet rs2=selcod.executeQuery("select nombre, apellidos, edad, calle, numero, codigopostal from alumnos where clave="+comboBox.getSelectedItem());
                txtNombre1.setText(rs2.getString(2));
                txtApellidos1.setText(rs2.getString(3));
                txtEdad1.setText(rs2.getString(4));
                txtCalle1.setText(rs2.getString(5));
                txtNumero1.setText(rs2.getString(6));
                txtCP1.setText(rs2.getString(7));

            } catch(SQLException ex){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
            } catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
            } finally{
                try{
                    if(conexion!=null){
                        conexion.close();
                    }
                } catch(SQLException exc){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, exc.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: You didn't provide what you try so far. This kind of a case you can't expect an answer.

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341755/filling-a-combo-box-with-mysql-data)

Comment: or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619403/how-do-i-populate-a-jcombobox-with-information-from-a-mysql-database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a loadcombo() to load your combobox with database values.

```
void loadcombo() {
    try
    {
    // Your database connections 

rs= st.executeQuery("select Column from Table");
    while(rs.next()){                            
        jComboBox.addItem(rs.getString(1));
    }
    con.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error"+e);
    }    
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
ResultSet rs2=selcod.executeQuery("select nombre, apellidos, edad, calle, numero, codigopostal from alumnos where clave="+comboBox.getSelectedItem());
            txtNombre1.setText(rs2.getString(2));
            txtApellidos1.setText(rs2.getString(3));
            txtEdad1.setText(rs2.getString(4));
            txtCalle1.setText(rs2.getString(5));
            txtNumero1.setText(rs2.getString(6));
            txtCP1.setText(rs2.getString(7));
```

In this if you are manually writing column names then you need to start with the 1 like `rs.getString(1)`

Just replace it with

```
ResultSet rs2=selcod.executeQuery("select nombre, apellidos, edad, calle, numero, codigopostal from alumnos where clave="+comboBox.getSelectedItem());
          if(rs2.next()){
            txtNombre1.setText(rs2.getString(1));
            txtApellidos1.setText(rs2.getString(2));
            txtEdad1.setText(rs2.getString(3));
            txtCalle1.setText(rs2.getString(4));
            txtNumero1.setText(rs2.getString(5));
            txtCP1.setText(rs2.getString(6));
          }
```

Comment: Now I need to load this data to at the start of the program and I need to show in textarea all the data of the tables and when I change the option in the combobox the textarea will update the data. I put the code here.

Comment: You mean to say jComboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){});

Comment: I put the code up in the question. I add the action listener and when I execute the program it doesn't show anything in the combobox

Comment: Actually you don't need to do that. Don't load your combobox again it will be same all the time. Just load it once. Just remove ResultSet rs=selcod.executeQuery("select clave from alumnos");
                while(rs.next()){
                    comboBox.addItem(rs.getString(1));
                }

Comment: Now it appears but it doesn't show any data in the textarea and when I change the option in the combobox it shows the follow error message: Before start of result set

Comment: See the  my edit and follow it.

Comment: I copy and paste the code you put but I have the same error and doesn't appear any data. Thank you for your help.

Comment: It is by mistake see the edit.

Comment: It works now, thank you. I also forget the method next() and I was going crazy looking for a solution. Thanks for all.

Answer (score 2):

You can use following code:

```
JComboBox cmb = your-combo;
ResultSet rs = your-Result-set; 
while(rs.next()) {
    String result = rs.getString(1); // Retrieves the value of the designated column in the current row of this ResultSet object as a String
    if (result != null) {
        result = result.trim();
    }
    cmb.addItem(result);
} 
rs.close();
```