# Populate a JComboBox using SQL

Tags: java, sql

I am currently doing a diploma course in Java and for our project we have to create a Restaurant Calculator(See screenshot), I have the majority of the GUI done but I am having great difficulty with the SQL. I have never used SQL before so I'm not 100% certain what to do. I understand how it works but I can't even run the SQL file that the college supplied us in MySQL. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated as I am really struggling with this. I have had this GUI done the past 2 weeks and have been searching online for help but cannot get my head around it

[image]

Code is below...

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class RestaurantCalculator {

private static JTextField TotalText;
private static JTextField TaxText;
private static JTextField Table;
private static JTextField Sub;
private static JTextField WName;
private static JComboBox BevMenu;
private static JComboBox AppMenu;
private static JComboBox MainMenu;
private static JComboBox DesMenu;



public static void testFun(String myName){
    TotalText.setText(myName);
}

public static void addComponentsToPane(Container pane){
    pane.setLayout(null);

    Border border = BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder();
    Border button = BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder();

   JLabel Welcome = new JLabel("Restaurant");
          Welcome.setBounds(250, 5, 150, 100);
          Welcome.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.BOLD, 20));


   JLabel Waiter = new JLabel("Waiter Information");
          Waiter.setBounds(100, 100, 200, 100);
          Waiter.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.BOLD, 14));

   JLabel Tableno = new JLabel("Table number:");
          Tableno.setBounds(120, 130, 200, 100);
          Tableno.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.BOLD, 12));


   JLabel WaiterName = new JLabel("Waiter Name:");
          WaiterName.setBounds(120, 160, 200, 100);
          WaiterName.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.BOLD, 12));

    JLabel MenuItems = new JLabel("Menu Items");
           MenuItems.setBounds(100, 220, 150, 100);
           MenuItems.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.BOLD, 14));

    JLabel Beverage = new JLabel("Beverage:");
           Beverage.setBounds(120, 250, 200, 100);
           Beverage.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.BOLD, 12));

    JLabel Appetizer = new JLabel("Appetizer:");
           Appetizer.setBounds(120, 280, 200, 100);
           Appetizer.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.BOLD, 12));

    JLabel MainCourse = new JLabel("Main Course:");
           MainCourse.setBounds(120, 310, 200, 100);
           MainCourse.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.BOLD, 12));

    JLabel Dessert = new JLabel("Dessert:");
           Dessert.setBounds(120, 340, 200, 100);
           Dessert.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.BOLD, 12));

    JLabel SubTotal = new JLabel("Sub Total:");
           SubTotal.setBounds(120, 440, 200, 100);
           SubTotal.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.BOLD, 12));

    JLabel Tax = new JLabel("Tax:");
           Tax.setBounds(120, 470, 200, 100);
           Tax.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.BOLD, 12));

    JLabel Total = new JLabel("Total:");
           Total.setBounds(120, 500, 200, 100);
           Total.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.BOLD, 12));


     Table = new JTextField(10);
                 Table.setBounds(290, 171, 150, 20);
                 Table.setBorder(border);

     WName = new JTextField(11);
               WName.setBounds(290, 201, 150, 20);
               WName.setBorder(border);             

     Sub = new JTextField(10);
               Sub.setBounds(260,482,150, 20);
               Sub.setBorder(border);
               Sub.setEditable(false);

     TotalText = new JTextField(10);
               TotalText.setBounds(260,545,150, 20);
               TotalText.setBorder(border);
               TotalText.setEditable(false);

     TaxText = new JTextField(10);
               TaxText.setBounds(260,515,150, 20);
               TaxText.setBorder(border);
               TaxText.setEditable(false);

     BevMenu = new JComboBox();
               BevMenu.setBounds(290, 295, 180, 20);

     AppMenu = new JComboBox();
               AppMenu.setBounds(290, 325, 180, 20);

     MainMenu = new JComboBox();
               MainMenu.setBounds(290, 355, 180, 20);

     DesMenu = new JComboBox();
               DesMenu.setBounds(290, 385, 180, 20);


        JButton     calculateJButton;
               calculateJButton = new JButton( "Calculate Bill" );
               calculateJButton.setBounds(250,425, 170, 30);
               calculateJButton.setBorder(button);









   pane.add(Welcome);       
   pane.add(Waiter);
   pane.add(Tableno);
   pane.add(WaiterName);
   pane.add(MenuItems);
   pane.add(Beverage);
   pane.add(Appetizer);
   pane.add(MainCourse);
   pane.add(Dessert);
   pane.add(SubTotal);
   pane.add(Tax);
   pane.add(Total);
   pane.add(Table);
   pane.add(WName);
   pane.add(Sub);
   pane.add(TaxText);
   pane.add(TotalText);
   pane.add(calculateJButton);
   pane.add(BevMenu);
   pane.add(AppMenu);
   pane.add(MainMenu);
   pane.add(DesMenu);



}

/**
 * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
 * this method should be invoked from the
 * event-dispatching thread.
 */
private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Restaurant Bill Calculator");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Set up the content pane.
    addComponentsToPane(frame.getContentPane());

    //Size and display the window.
    Insets insets = frame.getInsets();
    frame.setSize(600 + insets.left + insets.right,
                  700 + insets.top + insets.bottom);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
    //creating and showing this application's GUI.
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
            String theBest = "test";
            testFun(theBest);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: FIrst try to understand the JDBC and how to connect to a database through the Java. If youo have a basic understanding of JDBC you have to query the particular table and get the data and add that to the combobox model and set that model to the combobox. There are plenty of examples online. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21430325/set-result-of-mysql-query-into-a-jcombobox